# How can I access my Laravel app from another PC?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to access my Laravel app from another PC in the same network using IP address but I can't get it to work by accessing 192.168.1.101:8000 in my browser.

What should I do?

Comment: which server are you using?

Comment: make sure you have `Listen *:80` in your `httpd.conf`

Comment: you should post the relevant snippets from `httpd.conf` also, what url are you using locally?

Comment: i dont understand. how can i do that?

Comment: Thank you bro Mustafa Ehsan, this artisan command still works on Laravel 10

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Why don't you use Laravel's artisan for it? Very simple:

```
sudo php artisan serve --host 192.168.1.101 --port 80
```

Now from other computers, you can type: **http://192.168.1.101**

Do not forget to replace the IP with your own local one. That's it.

**Note:** The `sudo` is only needed if you wanna serve on port **80**.

Comment: Quick note for newbies: In Windows, you can view your computer's ip by typing "ipconfig" (without quotes) in the command line. Use that ip instead of the 192.168.1.101 (which is an example).
I've been looking for this simple answer all day. Thanks man. It works like a charm.

Comment: How about  `--host 0.0.0.0`? Laravel will listen in all IP interfaces.

Comment: Beautiful! And yes, be sure to run `ipconfig`/`ifconfig` to get your actual local `192.168.x.x` IP address for the command.

Comment: you sir have saved my time. trying to connect api on laravel with expo react native.. thank you

Comment: Note: Replace the IP with your comp IP

Comment: thank you for helping this is exactly what i was needing

Comment: thank you, it's working on my android tv box and accessed via my mac

Comment: it only works in same network. How we run on different projects too?

Comment: it's not working on my laravel app, it shows blankpage on another device, im using laravel inertia-vue, what should I do?

Comment: i solve the problem after adding server.host configuration in my vite.config.js

Answer (score 41):

Access laravel using your IP address

```
php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

Now you can access laravel server by http://laravel-server-ip-address:8000

If you want to change the port as well then

```
php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8101
```

Now your laravel server is http://laravel-server-ip-address:8101

Comment: How to create or find "laravel-server-ip-address"?

Comment: I found it. In Mac, System Preferences > Network and there is IP address under the Status

Answer (score 9):

1. Go to `httpd.conf` in Apache folder and find the following lines:

   ```
   DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
   <Directory "c:/wamp/www">
       # ...Stuffs in here
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       # ...Stuffs in here
       AllowOverride All
       #
       # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
       #
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
   ```
2. Then replace the last line *within* `<Directory>` tag for:

   ```
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
        Allow from ::1
        Allow from localhost
   </Directory>
   ```
3. Add a *virtual host* for your laravel application, go to `httpd-vhosts.conf` and add the following lines:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot "D:/.../your-laravel-app-path/public"
       ServerName yourservername.dev
       <Directory "D:/.../your-laravel-app-path/public">
           AllowOverride All
           Order deny,allow
           Allow from all
           Require all granted
       </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
4. Restart all your apache services

This should do it, i'm using wamp on Windows and works for me.

Comment: after, i cant now access my app from another pc using ip address?

Comment: i edited my answer @seanarce , tell me if it's working now and if not, how your vhosts conf look like

Answer (score 4):

Use this command in which ip address is ip-v4. Check ip-v4 from your wifi connection properties.

```
php artisan serve --host 192.168.10.15 --port 5000
```

Comment: I am trying on mac os. I get 

[Sun Feb 18 11:15:01 2024] Failed to listen on 192.168.10.15:5000 (reason: Can't assign requested address)

Comment: I found it. In Mac, `System Preferences > Network` and there is IP address under the `Status`

Answer (score 1):

1. Find your machine local IP:

> ifconfig

2. Go to project folder and type following command:

> sudo php artisan serve --host your_ip --port your_port
>
> example:
>
> sudo php artisan serve --host 192.168.1.70 --port 8080

3. Browse form other computer:

> 192.168.1.70:8080

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using laravel's built in command `php artisan serve`.

Follow the steps:

1. Go to your project's root directory within command line.
2. run `php artisan serve`

If you still can't access port 8000 **or** it is already in use then run:

```
php artisan serve --port 8383
```

And it should listen on new port you provided. Also you can set other options for this command. Look for the help `php artisan help serve`.

Comment: im trying to access my laravel application from another pc. i know this one but thank you anyway

Comment: @sean arce: i'm using the same for my production with multiple systems, and it's working fine from another PC. can you show me the actual error you get while accessing from another pc?

Comment: Unable to connect

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 192.168.1.3:8000.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web. -----------------------------i get this error

Comment: @sean arce: it's seems like there is some problem with your network connection, check that and make sure that your pc is connected properly.

Comment: What about Mac OS? I run the Laravel project over a local network IP address but a browser said such a network was blocked. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I have this set up in the office so that other users can get on to our developer system,

1. Don't worry about running serve with a host and port, run it like
   you normally would through your xampp.
2. List item Set up their host file with 192.168.1.101 Laravel.site
   (make sure your internal IP hasn't changed)
3. One of the problems I have encountered is your Windows
   firewall blocking traffic through port 80 internally, so you may
   have to allow xampp in your local firewall

Hope this helps :)