# How can i access a second laravel app from another pc

Tags: php, laravel

On this link:
[how can i access my laravel app from another pc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28956911/how-can-i-access-my-laravel-app-from-another-pc)

It is perfectly described how to access an laravel app from another pc on the same network.
Now, my question is:

How to access another app served on the same pc?

I have a virtual machine serving two apps app.dev and demo.dev
both are accessible inside VM through internet browser

app.dev is accessible on http://localhost and http://app.dev
demo.dev is accessible only on http://demo.dev

Outside VM only app.dev is accessible on IP address 192.168.0.60

i have used this command inside VM

```
sudo php artisan serve --host 192.168.0.60 --port 80
```

Should i use again

```
sudo php artisan serve ????
```

but how? anybody help?

Comment: Are you using Homestead?

Comment: No, i have installed laravel on my Ubuntu VM

Comment: Is that PC on LAN @lewis4u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel's `artisan serve` command uses the [PHP Built-in web server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php). Because that is not a full featured web server, it has no concept of virtual hosts, so it can only run one instance of the server mapped to an IP and port pair.

Normally to serve two hosts from the same IP address you'd add in your VM's `/etc/hosts` file the following mappings:

```
192.168.0.60 app.dev
192.168.0.60 demo.dev
```

Now you can run `app.dev` by running:

```
php artisan serve --host app.dev --port 80
```

And it will be available on your host machine using http://app.dev. However if you would try to spin up a second server instance for `demo.dev` using this:

```
php artisan serve --host demo.dev --port 80
```

It **won't work** and will complain that:

> Address already in use

You could get around that by using a different port for your `demo.dev` app by using for example this:

```
php artisan serve --host demo.dev --port 8080
```

And now you'd be able to access http://demo.dev:8080 for your second app on your host machine.

---

That being said, I suggest you install a full featured web server such as Apache or nginx and then setup a virtual host for each application (just make sure to keep the mappings from the `/etc/hosts` file I showcased above).

Setting up virtual hosts can be really easy for both server solutions. Below are links to two articles from the Laravel Recipes website that showcase how to do that specifically for Laravel:

> [Creating an Apache VirtualHost](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/25/creating-an-apache-virtualhost)
>
> [Creating a Nginx VirtualHost](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/26/creating-a-nginx-virtualhost)

Comment: unfortunatelly it doesn't work with php artisan serve --host demo.dev --port 8080.....inside VM works on localhost:8080 and demo.dev --- but from 192.168.0.60:8080 it doesn't....i have apache installed and i have created a virtual host and edited /etc/hosts --- maybe i'm missing something more...even apache restarted

Comment: Sorry, you should have those `hosts` mappings on your host machine, since otherwise it can't resolve the IP address of the VM to a hostname.

Comment: I have solved it. /etc/apache2/ports.conf must be edited because apache only listens on port 80. i added just one more line Listen 8080 and it works now!

Comment: If you're using Apache you can have many apps on the same port. So with Apache if you have two separate virtual hosts, using http://app.dev and http://demo.dev will both work on port 80. That wasn't possible just for `artisan serve`.

Comment: yes everything is fine on Ubuntu VM but i can't access it from windows host machine...i even edited windows host file and added both apps demo.dev and app.dev to point to 192.168.0.60 and when i ping demo.dev or app.dev it resolves to 127.0.53.53

Comment: I have finally solved it. .dev domain is not welcome i needed to chane all my apps to .com and NOW it works!