# How to run a shell_exec() in php that will not stop unless killed or stopped?

Tags: php, windows, laravel

I am building a Laravel Application for offline mode only (for Windows OS only). There is a client and server setup.

In the server dashboard, there is a button to "Turn on" the Server to allow the client to connect to the server. Reference ([how can i access my laravel app from another pc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28956911/how-can-i-access-my-laravel-app-from-another-pc))

My code is not working.

```
// Route
Route::post('server-on', 'ServerController@powerOn')->name('server-on'); 

// ServerController
public function powerOn(){
    $ip = getHostByName(getHostName()); // IPv4 Address (192.168.254.120)
    $command = 'php artisan serve --host ' . $ip . '  --port 1807 2>&1 &';
    shell_exec($command);
}
```

The reason why I have this, is to assume that the End User are non-techie. I don't want them open the cmd and enter the command (that could be my last resort).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shell_exec()` got nothing to do with it. If your app runs on Linux then to have executed program keep running in background while invocation call returns immediately you have to use helpers, like like [nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) (and remove trailing `&`):

```
$command = "nohup php artisan serve --host {$ip} --port 1807 2>&1";
...
```

**EDIT**

> I'm using Windows.

If so, the first, your former `$command` is invalid on Windows platform due to how you tried to redirect i/o streams (and also because of use of `&`).
None the less, to run stuff in background on Windows, you also need a helper, like `START` ([docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start)).

See related question on Superuser: [How can I execute a Windows command line in background?](https://superuser.com/a/591084).

Comment: I'm using Windows.

Comment: `"start /MIN cmd /k php ../artisan serve --host {$ip}  --port 1807 " ` solved my Problem. Thanks for the references and idea.