# Failed to connect to /192.168.43.23 (port 8000) from /192.168.43.1 (port 47726) after 10000ms

Tags: java, android, laravel, android-studio, retrofit

I am creating a `Login Activity` in `Android Studio` using `Laravel REST API`. I run the application on a `real device (Android version 9)`. The API worked in Postman but not in the app. My computer's IP address is 192.168.43.23. When I try to login, here's the error `Failed to connect to /192.168.43.23 (port 8000) from /192.168.43.1 (port 47726) after 10000ms`. Do you have any idea how to solve it? Thank you. Here's my code in `LoginActivity.java`:

```
private void login(String email, String password) {
    apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<Login> loginCall = apiInterface.loginResponse(email, password);
    loginCall.enqueue(new Callback<Login>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Login> call, Response<Login> response) {
            if(response.body() != null && response.isSuccessful() && response.body().isStatus()){

                sessionManager = new SessionManager(LoginActivity.this);
                LoginData loginData = response.body().getLoginData();
                sessionManager.createLoginSession(loginData);

                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, response.body().getLoginData().getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intentLogin = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentLogin);
                finish();

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, response.body().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Login> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sessionManager = new SessionManager(MainActivity.this);
    if(!sessionManager.isLoggedIn()){
        moveToLogin();
    }
}

private void moveToLogin() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

ApiClient.Java

```
public class ApiClient {
private static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.43.23:8000/api/";

private static Retrofit retrofit;

public static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (retrofit == null){
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

ApiInterface.java

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface ApiInterface {

   @FormUrlEncoded
   @POST("loginPassenger")
   Call<Login> loginResponse(
        @Field("email") String email,
        @Field("password") String password
   );
 }
```

Login.java

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Login{

   @SerializedName("data")
   private LoginData loginData;

   @SerializedName("message")
   private String message;

   @SerializedName("status")
   private boolean status;

   public void setLoginData(LoginData loginData){
       this.loginData = loginData;
   }

   public LoginData getLoginData(){
       return loginData;
   }

   public void setMessage(String message){

       this.message = message;
   }

   public String getMessage(){
       return message;
   }

   public void setStatus(boolean status){
       this.status = status;
   }

   public boolean isStatus(){
       return status;
   }
   }
```

LoginData.java

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class LoginData {

   @SerializedName("password")
   private String password;

   @SerializedName("contact")
   private String contact;

   @SerializedName("name")
   private String name;

   @SerializedName("updated_at")
   private Object updatedAt;

   @SerializedName("id_users")
   private String idUsers;

   @SerializedName("created_at")
   private Object createdAt;

   @SerializedName("gender")
   private int gender;

   @SerializedName("email")
   private String email;

   @SerializedName("username")
   private String username;

   @SerializedName("address")
   private String address;

   public void setPassword(String password){
       this.password = password;
   }

   public String getPassword(){
       return password;
   }

   public void setContact(String contact){
       this.contact = contact;
   }

   public String getContact(){
       return contact;
   }

   public void setName(String name){
       this.name = name;
   }

   public String getName(){
       return name;
   }

   public void setUpdatedAt(Object updatedAt){
       this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
   }

   public Object getUpdatedAt(){
       return updatedAt;
   }

   public void setIdUsers(String idUsers){
       this.idUsers = idUsers;
   }

   public String getIdUsers(){
       return idUsers;
   }

   public void setCreatedAt(Object createdAt){
       this.createdAt = createdAt;
   }

   public Object getCreatedAt(){
       return createdAt;
   }

   public void setGender(int gender){
       this.gender = gender;
   }

   public int getGender(){
       return gender;
   }

   public void setEmail(String email){
       this.email = email;
   }

   public String getEmail(){
       return email;
   }

   public void setUsername(String username){
       this.username = username;
   }

   public String getUsername(){
       return username;
   }

   public void setAddress(String address){
       this.address = address;
   }

   public String getAddress(){
       return address;
   } 
   }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.passengerApp">

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

   <application
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
       android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
       android:supportsRtl="true"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
       android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
       <activity android:name=".AccountActivity"/>
       <activity android:name=".MyOrderActivity" />
       <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
       <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
       <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
   </application>
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.passengerApp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard- rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:30'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.1'
    implementation 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}
```

network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.43.23:8000</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: `My IP address is 192.168.43.23` Of you? Or from the server device? Or from client device?

Comment: My computer's IP Address

Comment: What has your computer to do with this all? You have not mentioned your computer before.

Comment: Pardon me, I use local api

Comment: What has it to do with your computer is still the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

is your api working from the browser of your phone?
check to see if your api sends the right response from chrome or any browser from your smartphone.

Comment: Excuse me, should I type `http://192.168.43.23:8000/api/loginPassenger` on my chrome? Thank you

Comment: yes if you have a 192.168.43.23:8000/api/loginPassenger endpoint on your api.php file. Just to see if the endpoints are accessible and not blocked by firewall, return a string to see if the string response is received on the client browser. tell me what happens

Comment: It says The site can't be reached

Comment: yes i think you can access the url in your computer's browser but can't access it on your mobile's browser. And, the problem is that server(or project) is accepting reqquests only from your local computer. To solve this see [https://stackoverflow.com/a/28958400/9372961] . You don't need to do the third step. But try it if it number one and two does not work. Also, restart your server before you try again and let me know.

Comment: I tried `php artisan serve --host 192.168.43.23 --port 8000` and it works. Thank you so much for your help.